# How to stretch an input to width of div without it having affect the size of a span element before it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

To clarify I have a form with a span and an input:

```
<form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <Box className='form_box'>
                        <span>
                            guest@website.com:: {'~ >>'}
                        </span>

                        <input value={user_input} onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)} />
                    </Box>
                </form>
```

```
.form_box{
    background-color: beige;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    input{
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
    }

}
```

I want to make the input element stretch across the entire width of its parent 'form_box' div. When I try to use `width: 100%` it results in the span element that is in front of the input field to stretch across two lines, as if the text inside is to long for the container.

Clarity:

```
guest@website: ____ <- original
```

```
guest@ __________________ <- what happens if i try to set width to 100%

website
```

Any help with a css solution greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. I would suggest that you have a working example and more related html/css than this. There is no related css to anything. I'm just saying this because your question will be closed unless it has.

Comment: Maybe adding `white-space:  nowrap;` to the Box

Comment: Add flex: 1; to your input

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flexbox to make the last item in the Box expand to fill the remaining space:

```
    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
      <Box
        className="form_box"
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          // make last item in flexbox fill remaining space
          "& > :last-child": { flexGrow: 1 },
        }}
      >
        <span>guest@website.com:: {"~ >>"}</span>

        <input
          value={user_input}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Box>
    </form>
```

or, if you wanted to keep your styles in a separate file:

```
.form_box {
  background-color: beige;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: "row";
}

.form_box > :last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 1000;
}
```